# Wrongly formatted div in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, format, positioning

I have  the following html and css codes:

The problem is that  is properly displayed for IE10 & Chrome (at the right down corner of header_container section).

But in Firefox:   is displayed in right-down corner of browser (or   -Strange:)).

How to fix that behavior  in Firefox?

Code here:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <LINK href="LayoutWithDivsLikeTables3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="main_container">
        <div id="header_container">     
            <h1>Title Title Title</h1>      
            <div id="top_menu"> Top Menu | Top Menu | Top Menu | Top Menu | Top Menu |</div>
        </div>  

        <div id="row">
            <div id="left" >
                <h4>Left Col</h4>
                <p>...</p>
            </div>

            <div id="middle">
                <h4>Middle Col</h4>
                <p>...</p><p>...</p>
            </div>

            <div id="right">
                <h4>Right Col</h4>
                <p>...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">Footer</div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>

body    {
    margin: 0px; 
    width: 100%; 
    height:100%;
}

#top_menu   {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px; right: 0px; 
    //width: 250px;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding:5px;
}

#header_container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    border:  1px solid black;
    display: table-caption;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

#footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    border:  1px solid yellow;
    display: table-row;
}

#main_container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    }

#row{
    //height: 33%;
    display: table-row;
    }

#left { background-color: blue; width: 150px;}
#right { background-color: red; width: 150px;}
#middle {  background-color: yellow;}

#left, #right, #middle 
{
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px black;
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful for us if you create fiddle for the same. (in jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/0x3w71w2/

Comment: It's the `display:table-caption` that makes the `position:relative` being ignored in Fx. I will look a bit to see if that is right or wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change something in your html code to set the table to start with the content and let the header and footer to have only display:block.

http://jsfiddle.net/v1ycfn8m/1/

```
#top_menu   {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px; right: 0px; 
    font-size: 13px;
    padding:5px;
}

#header_container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    border:  1px solid black;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

#footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    border:  1px solid yellow;
    display: block;
}

#main_container {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#row{
    display: table-row;
}

#table {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
```

and

```
   <div id="table">
        <div id="row">
            <div id="left" >
                <h4>Left Col</h4>
                <p>...</p>
            </div>

            <div id="middle">
                <h4>Middle Col</h4>
                <p>...</p><p>...</p>
            </div>

            <div id="right">
                <h4>Right Col</h4>
                <p>...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't combine `display: table-caption` and `position: relative`.

According to the standard, the behaviour when doing so is undefined, so there is no wrong behaviour:

> "The effect of 'position:relative' on table-row-group,
>   table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-row, table-column-group,
>   table-column, table-cell, and table-caption elements is undefined."

Ref: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-position

You either have to pick another `display` setting for the header, or use a different way of placing the menu. You could for example wrap the content of the header in a div, which could take the `position: relative` setting.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `#top_menu` css property `position:absolute`. Now menu will show on top. And then set accordingly where you want to place it.

Comment: So now I have it like this: #top_menu  {
 //position: absolute;
 bottom: 10px; right: 0px; 
 width: 250px;
 font-size: 13px;
 padding:5px;
}. Menu is displyed properly but on the left but how to move it  to right down corner of header?

Comment: Now is the menu showing on header in all browsers i.e FF, IE & Chrome?

Comment: Deepak,please reread my comment. Now I dont know how to move this internal div to right top corner.

Comment: Set the menu width same as Header width and then set `text-align:right` and if you want some padding then add `padding-right:5px`. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox, "display: table-caption" ignores "position: relative" property.

Here is one more way to solve this problem, without using css table layout.

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x5s3eff8/1/)

In the above demo I have used the default behavior of div element (which is nothing but block element and utilizes 100% width of its parent element)

Modified CSS :

```
body    {
    margin: 0px; 
    width: 100%; 
    height:100%;
}

#top_menu   {
    text-align: right;
   font-size: 13px;
    padding:5px;
}

#header_container {
    border:  1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
}

#footer {
    width: 100%;
    clear: left;
    height: 150px;
    border:  1px solid yellow;
}


#left { background-color: blue; width: 33%;}
#right { background-color: red;width: 33%; }
#middle {  background-color: yellow; width: 34%;}

#left, #right, #middle 
{
    float: left;
    border: 1px black;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I tried this one too, but when one column contains more data, these 3 columns has different height, which is not requested in this design.